# Ajax Update Cart Summary Magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, component

In shoping cart **(checkout_cart_index**). When I use bullet to increase qty then i use ajax to update cart.

After call ajax how to update cart summary.

Comment: go to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142023/magento-2-update-cart-summary-html/144316#144316 link for solution.