# Magento 2 : Update Cart summary html

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, shopping-cart, totals

When I use a bullet to increase qty then I use ajax to update cart. After call ajax how to update cart summary. I am stuck here please help me out from this.

also, I used

```
$("#cart-totals").trigger('contentUpdated');
```

line in response but its not working :( :(

Comment: Refer this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233080/how-to-reload-shopping-cart-summary-via-ajax-in-magento-2-2#answer-233124

Comment: Refer This : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233080/how-to-reload-shopping-cart-summary-via-ajax-in-magento-2-2#answer-233124

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update cart summary in ajax response has been solved, we need to call getTotalsAction() javascript function as i mentioned below code :

demo.js

```
 define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'
        ], function ($, getTotalsAction) {
        "use strict";

          $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: demoUrl, //your ajax Url
                data: {/*here post data*/},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (resp) {
                   //below two lines refershing cart summary
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred); //this function already created in Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals.js file
                }

            });

});
```

Comment: where i need to put this js?

Comment: please enhance your answer or you deserve a down vote

Comment: Can you please write full code to update table and summary when change quantity from cat page?

Comment: @Lucky Awesome this is exactly what I needed to know! thanks.

Comment: I try this solution but on console show TypeError: options is undefined error . please help to solve this error

Comment: Can you add full code here

Comment: Thanks, It work and  refreshes cart summary but how can i get update cart subtotal here, when i fetch subtotal is give previous subtotal

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the summary block, by simply triggering the Magento estimateTotals function, by using the following code:

```
require(
[
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
   ],

    function(
        quote,
        totalsDefaultProvider
    ) {
        totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
    }
);
```

References:

https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/magento2-triggering-totals-refresh-in-cart/

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ac1e74c87bae0bf99f427f3279c4a90856142590/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/estimate-service.js#L55

Comment: This is not working

Comment: This part update totals with correct shipping totals